# React Native: Can a module in one node_modules folder access modules from a different node_modules?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, node-modules, package.json, react-native-screens

In my React Native app I'm using `react-navigation-tabs`, for which you need to separately install several other modules such as `react-native-screens`. I made a custom version of `react-navigation-tabs` in `./Custom/react-navigation-tabs`. What I want to know is, do I need to go into the `./Custom/react-navigation-tabs` folder and add `react-native-screens` from there? Or can I do it in the root of the project?